# Install DC again after removing on exchange server

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, domain-controller, active-directory

I had a DC and Exchange 2010 installed on the same machine. I removed the DC role, and Exchange server went crazy. I tried to install the DC role again to fix the problem but ran into this error when running `DCPROMO`:

```
Active Directory Domain Services could not create the NTDS Settings object for this Active Directory Domain Controller CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC1,CN=Servers,CN=Manukau,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=AccessGroupnz,DC=com on the remote AD DC Server1.AccessGroupnz.com. 

Ensure the provided network credentials have sufficient permissions.

"The DSA operation is unable to proceed because of a DNS lookup failure."
```

Do you think I need to run this in an elevated command prompt, or change credentials somewhere to domain admin?  Or is it something else?

Comment: Was this the only domain controller in your domain when you removed it?

Comment: Apart from @pauska question, if you have another DC, did you change the primary DNS on the Exchange box to point to another DC?